# Unable to update task associations

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I defined my custom workflow with alfresco/activiti. In my model i defined custom aspect which beside some properties has associations which will represent members of some team

```
<aspects>
    <aspect name="mcwm:projectCharter">
         <properties>
                  ........
                <property name="cm:userName">
                 ..........
                </property>
          </properties>
          <associations>
                <association name="mcwm:teamWithDoc">
                        <source>
                              <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                              <many>false</many>
                       </source>
                       <target>
                               <class>cm:person</class>
                               <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                               <many>true</many>
                         </target>
                </association>
      </associations>
```

Now, in my workflow i have 5 tasks, and on every task i set mandatory aspect which i described above.

```
<type name="mcwm:submitStart">
  <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
  <mandatory-aspects>
     <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
     <aspect>mcwm:projectCharter</aspect>
  </mandatory-aspects>
```

The problem is that if some user for example on beginning of process on task 1 set association mcwm:teamWithDoc (pick members of team from alfresco repository), property is nice passed to task 2. But if some other user which is assigned to task 2 change mcwm:teamWithDoc (e.g. add some more team members or delete some team members) on task 3 these changes are not seen. On task 3 mcwm:teamWithDoc has value which is set on start task. The same case is with other task, whatever other users done with mcwm:teamWithDoc on task 2, task 3 or task 4, mcwm:teamWithDoc always has value which is set on beginning?

Any idea how to update this association?

P.S. I update my regular properties between task using execution.setVariable('propertName', task.getVariable('propertName')); but for association this isn't functioning.

Regards,
Aleksandar

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using that method, you could better use the [task controller](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration#Process_Data)  with the use of the task controller you can easily get the association. Check the [wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.4_JavaScript_API#Root_Scope_Objects) for more info on how to get the association.

E.g. it will look like the following:

```
<controller>
    <variable name="prop" access="read,write" mapped-name="mcwm_projectCharter"/>
</controller>
```

so then you have the mcwm_projectCharter mapped to prop. So with that you can do a prop.assocs["mcwm:teamWithDoc"][0] to get the first or iterate through it.

Comment: I am using Activiti not JBPM, is this controller available in Activiti? Also i don't have problem with accessing to association (i'm doing that from Java class and that's fine). My problem is how to pass association value between task, or exactly if my association is updated on one task how i can see those changes on my other task? In my situation user on task 1 set pick up some teamMembers and if user on Task2, 3 or 4 change these teamMembers changes aren't reflected, on Task2, 3 or 4 teamMember association still has value which is picked on first step.

Comment: You need to save the value of the association of that task in a general value and use that. The task instance values/properties are gone when ended. So you need to define a Proces var which holds the actual value and push and pull it.

Comment: I put association value from first task to global value. On my second task i have completely different association (different variable). On second task create i set this second variable to the value of global value just to user can what was typed on previous task. On second task complete i want to pick value of second task association to put her on global variable, but second task association value is not updated even user pick something during task, her value is the same as i set on task create. Looks like the value of association can be set only once?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you problems is relative to this bug
https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-13640.

Once you have set the value of an associtaiton you con not change it!!!

Comment: Hi Francesco. O know that (i forgot to past it here), my team lead reported that bug, it was blocker for us. Thank you anyway. :)